# Civi Postcode webform widget not updating

Tags: webform-civicrm

We've got the civi postcode extension and related weborm widget integration module installed on a site

Postcode look up works fine in civi, and on existing configured forms

Trying to update a postode field from text to look up using the change widget feature leeds purely to a blank screen

/node/xxx/webform/components/xx?type=civipostcode

Looking in the error log a notification occurs at the same time as trying to update widget  /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml- page not found

Anyone any ideas what could be casuing this
(civi 5.3.1, drupal 7.59)